# Content Security Polity bloquea tag manager de Google aunque le diga que no lo haga

Tags: html, asp.net, csp

Tengo una parte de una web que está bloqueando el acceso al googletagmanager por políticas de seguridad.
El mensaje es el siguiente:

```
Content Security Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-xxxxxx (script-src).
```

He probado a añadirle una etiqueta meta para que me deje poner cualquier cosa (por probar y luego ir restringiendo más):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  
        content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
                 script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Pero lo sigue bloqueando. He probado muchas variantes y nunca deja de bloquearlo.
Por ejemplo cosas así en el meta de antes:

```
*.googletagmanager.com 
*.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js 
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js
... etc.
```

¿Cómo debería ponerlo para que deje de bloquearlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias opciones, la recomendada que es

> OPCION 1: Una de ellas es usar un nonce o un hash. El método recomendado es usar un nonce, que debe ser un valor aleatorio e impredecible que el servidor genera únicamente para cada respuesta.

Seria la opcion 1 algo asi

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  
    content="default-src * 'nonce-{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}' ;
             script-src * www.googletagmanager.com;">
```

Y en cada resppuesta deberias generar ese numero aleatatorio (cadena aleatoria) >> *{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}*

Y va como atributo nonce del del tag scripts

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script nonce='{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}'>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTa...
```

OPCION 2: Menos "segura", como lo tienes con **unsafe-inline**

script-src: 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googletagmanager.com
img-src: [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com)

Prueba asi en tu ejemplo

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  
    content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.googletagmanager.com;
             script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.googletagmanager.com; 
             img-src: www.googletagmanager.com">
```

Enlace que te puede servir de ayuda o guia

- [Usar Google Tag Manager con una política de seguridad del contenido](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp?hl=es)